# Decode URL into an array rather than a string

Tags: php

I am currently working with PayPals API and want to transform one of its response from a name-value pair to an array.

So far I have used `urldecode()` to decode the response to the following:

```
RECEIVERBUSINESS=foo@bar.com&RECEIVEREMAIL=another@email.com&MOREINFO=lots more info`
```

What I would like is to have the following:

```
RECEIVERBUSINESS => 'foo@bar.com'
RECEIVEREMAIL => 'another@email.com'
MOREINFO => 'lots more info'
```

I'm just not quite sure how to get there!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) is what you're looking for:

```
parse_str('RECEIVERBUSINESS=foo@bar.com&RECEIVEREMAIL=another@email.com&MOREINFO=lots more info', $arr);
/*
print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [RECEIVERBUSINESS] => foo@bar.com
    [RECEIVEREMAIL] => another@email.com
    [MOREINFO] => lots more info
)
*/
```

Answer (score -3):

Look into `explode` -

```
// poulate array from URL parameters
$returnedInfo = explode('&', $dataStringFromUrl);
```

http://us.php.net/explode