# How do I access objects, in PHP, in an array posted to PHP from ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am posting an array from javascript using AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {arr:fullData},

        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = data;

        },

        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
```

This is the array:

```
0: "event=200 Yard Free Style&swimmername=joe fish&lane=1&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=2&swimmername2=joe fish"
1: "event=200 Yard Free Style&swimmername=steve jobs&lane=3&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=4&swimmername2=steve jobs"
2: "event=200 Yard Free Style&swimmername=steve jobs&lane=5&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=6&swimmername2=steve jobs"
length: 3
```

In PHP, The array comes through like this:

```
array (size=1)
  'arr' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'event=200 Yard Free Style&swimmername=joe fish&lane=1&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=2&swimmername2=joe fish' (length=147)
      1 => string 'event=200 Yard Free Style&swimmername=steve jobs&lane=3&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=4&swimmername2=steve jobs' (length=151)
      2 => string 'event=200 Yard Free Style&swimmername=steve jobs&lane=5&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=6&swimmername2=steve jobs' (length=151)
```

I have tried using "explode()" but it keeps saying it can't explode an "array"

I am trying to do the following:

```
 $array = $_POST;
 var_dump ($array[0]['event'] );
```

and set the different values to build a sql query like so (in loop):

```
 foreach($_POST as $data)
{
    $sql_query = '(';

if(isset($array['event'])){$sql_query .= $array['event'] . ',';}
if(isset($array['event'])){$sql_query .= $array['swimmername'] . ',';}
```

I am new to PHP and having a tough time figuring it out.
Any help will be appreciated.

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$array = $_POST;

$array1 = $_REQUEST['arr'];
var_dump($array['arr']);

$returnedInfo = explode('&',$array[1]);
// Empty string when using an empty array:
echo ($returnedInfo);
$sql_query = 'INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (event,swimmername, lane, place, time, score,  )
    VALUES ';
$i = 0;
$arrayLength = count($_POST);
var_dump ($arrayLength);

foreach($_POST as $data)
{


    $sql_query = '(';
    if(isset($data['event'])){$sql_query .= $data['event'] . ',';}
    if(isset($data['swimmername'])){$sql_query .=  ','. $data['swimmername'] . ',';}
    if(isset($data['lane'])){$sql_query .=  ','.  $data['lane'] . ',';}
    if(isset($data['place'])){$sql_query .=  ','. $data['place'] . ',';}
    if(isset($data['time'])){$sql_query .=  ','. $data['time'] . ',';}
    if(isset($data['scoreA'])){$sql_query .=  ','.  $data['scoreA'] . ',';}
    if(isset($data['scoreB'])){$sql_query .=  ','. $data['scoreB'] . ',';}
    if(isset($data['time2'])){$sql_query .=  ','. $data['time2'] . ',';}
    if(isset($data['lane2'])){$sql_query .=  ','.  $data['lane2'] . ',';}
    if(isset($data['place2'])){$sql_query .=  ','. $data['place2'] . ',';}
    if(isset($data['swimmername2'])){$name2[] = $data['swimmername2'] . ',';}
    $i++;
    if($i < $arrayLength) {
        $sql_query .=  '),';
    } else {
        $sql_query .=  ');';
    }


}
// Then use $sql_query for the INSERT step.
?>
```

Comment: Look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507679/decode-url-into-an-array-rather-than-a-string

Comment: are you trying to `explode('&',$array)` or `explode('&',$array[0])` ?? It seems like the second version should work but the first would give the error you mentioned

Comment: I tried that, but my issue is when I use explode, I get:

explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
even though my output shows:  0 => string 'event=200 Yard Free

Comment: Let me try that. :-)

Comment: The key of the array is `arr`. The first level/dimension I mean.

Comment: I see.. which means it would be more like

`explode('&',$array['arr'][0])`  Or you would explode in a foreach loop on `$array['arr']`.   Or alternatively send the data from AJAX without the arr.

Comment: I still get:
Array to string conversion using: explode('&',$array['arr'][0])

Comment: You should really change the way data is coming to PHP... If it is from a form, serialize it.

Comment: It is not a form. I have a table and pushing the values of a table with 3 rows to the array and then posting it.

Comment: whats the result of `var_dump($array['arr'][0])`

Comment: Where do you do the explode ? You should show your code until the explode at least.

Comment: I am adding it to the question

Comment: the var_dump returns
string 'event=200 Yard Medley Relay&swimmername=joe fish&lane=1&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=2&swimmername2=martin tobias' (length=154)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array looks like this:

```
array (
  'arr' => 
  array (
    0 => 'event=200 Yard Free Style&swimmername=joe fish&lane=1&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=2&swimmername2=joe fish',
    1 => 'event=200 Yard Free Style&swimmername=steve jobs&lane=3&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=4&swimmername2=steve jobs',
    2 => 'event=200 Yard Free Style&swimmername=steve jobs&lane=5&time=00:00:00&place=0&scoreA=0&scoreB=0&place2=0&time2=00:00:00&lane2=6&swimmername2=steve jobs',
  ),
)
```

...you simply need to loop through it and use something like parse_str (easy) or explode (slightly more work) to transform each string into an array.  For example:

```
# Grab the 'arr' array
$realArray = isset($array['arr']) ? $array['arr'] : array();
foreach ( $realArray as $k => $v ) {
    # Quick and painless way to convert to array
    parse_str($v, $value);
    $realArray[$k] = $value;
}
# Put this into a function called 'debug' to make life easier
echo '<pre>';
var_export($realArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: That looks good. How can I get "event" = "200..." back as a separate object with out explode?

Comment: I get it:
var_export($value['event']);