# URL Encode To Array Using PHP?

Tags: php

I have these urlencode from Postmant:

```
rq_uuid=e53473de-0483-44f5-91f0-2be74e58c277&rq_datetime
=2022-03-09 16:33:16&sender_id=TESS&receiver_id=SGRQWES
```

How can I convert this URLENCODE in an array in PHP so i will have an array like this :

```
array(
'rq_uuid' => 'e53473de-0483-44f5-91f0-2be74e58c277',
'rq_datetime' => '2022-03-09 16:33:16',
'sender_id' => 'TESS',
'receiver_id' => 'SGRQWES',
etc..
)
```

Comment: [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) does exactly that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode URL into an array rather than a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507679/decode-url-into-an-array-rather-than-a-string)

Comment: For the record, *Decode*. If you wanted to *Encode*, you'd use [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query). As to why we don't have something like `http_query_encode` and `http_query_decode`,  or `http_parse_query` for the "decoder" part, but instead we have `http_build_query` and `parse_str` for its counterpart (that for some reason _must_ be used by reference), that's a question for the geniouses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> parse_str parses string as if it were the query string passed via a
> URL and sets variables in the current scope (or in the array if result
> is provided).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

```
parse_str("rq_uuid=e53473de-0483-44f5-91f0-2be74e58c277&
=2022-03-09 16:33:16&sender_id=TESS&receiver_id=SGRQWES", $arr_params);

print "<pre>";

print_r ($arr_params);

print "</pre>";
```

Comment: Its work..Tanks